# Using DLL import/Declare in VB.NET with parameter types not used by .NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I am working on a project where I have to import a DLL file into a VB project that was created a few years back. The DLL was created in C++, and looks like:

```
void CoordinateConversionService::convert( SourceOrTarget::Enum sourceDirection, SourceOrTarget::Enum targetDirection, CoordinateTuple* sourceCoordinates, Accuracy* sourceAccuracy, CoordinateTuple& targetCoordinates, Accuracy& targetAccuracy )
```

I am an intern at my job, and I haven't had to use this yet, so my understanding is extremely limited, along with my usage of VB (I'm a C++/C# guy). Here are a few questions:

1) Looking at Dllimport, it seems like the last part outside of the parameters is a return type. Example code from another site:

```
<DllImport("advapi32.dll")> _
  Public Function GetUserName( _
     ByVal lpBuffer As StringBuilder, _
     ByRef nSize As Integer) As Boolean
```

Is "As Boolean" the return type? If so, I tried using "Sub" and it says "Keyword does not name a type." Hence why I looked into declare, because it seems I CAN return void/sub as a return type.

2) Trying to use the types "CoordinateTuple" and "Accuracy" give me problems, saying that they aren't defined. How do I get around this since I don't think I can really define them, and what about the fact that they're pointers? Also - I cannot modify the C++ code in any way, so what I have is what I have.

Comment: PS - I tried adding this as a reference and I got the error that says that it is not a valid COM file.

Comment: We need more information about the custom types `SourceOrTarget::Enum`, `CoordinateTuple` and `Accuracy`. VB and C# can only handle plain C functions, no C++ functions (the marshaller was designed to provide simple access to the Windows API), so if these types are non-POD types, you must write a C++ wrapper with either a C or .NET interface. At the very least, you must get rid of the C++ reference parameters and declare the function `extern "C"`.

Comment: Are you talking about the C++ code? Because I cannot modify it in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB you say either `Public Function Whatever (params) As ReturnType` (which is the same as `public ReturnType Whatever(params)` in C#) or `Public Sub Whatever (params)` which is for things that don't return anything (return `void` in C++/C#).

If your function/sub takes custom types you will need to declare .NET equivalents to those as well. This can make PInvoke hard work. Tools like [the interop assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) can help.

Comment: So I'll essentially need to convert the types over from C++ to VB.net?

Comment: Yes. If you use the interop assistant you can basically paste in the C++ defs and it will give you VB to put before your DllImport statement.

Comment: Okay, cool. I'll test your method in a bit and then give you the answer if it works :)

Comment: +1 The interop assistant rocks! ibarczewski may need to copy in some bits of header files as well, so that the interop assistant knows what `CoordinateTuple` is etc

Answer (score 0):

For the custom types, you may have to create a wrapper in managed C++, which has the ability both to consume native C++ APIs and expose managed APIs. Although dated, a walkthrough can be found here:

- [Writing Managed Wrappers with Managed C++](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/03/29/mcpp_part3.html)

Comment: Only if the types are complicated. POD types are handled very well by the .NET marshaller.